# Gradle eclipse plugin for Eclipse Helios 3.6

Tags: gradle, eclipse-3.6, helios

I can not install gradle plugin for Eclipse Helios.

I have tried to install gradle plugin as it was mentioned here (http://docs.spring.io/sts/docs/2.9.0.old/reference/html/gradle/installation.html)

I have installed STS for Eclipse Helios via Eclipse Marketplace without any errors. Then I have tried to install gradle plugin via Help -> install new software and typed http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle. Tried to install gradle plugin, but installation hangs with the following picture for hours and plugin is not installed.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, found a solution: installed gradle integration via Spring dashboard Extensions sections after intallation of eclips STS plugin for Helios from eclipse market place. It took some time to install gradle plugin, but finally it was installed

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only one thing to mention in case you are unable to find DashBoard(It is opened by default,but if you ever closed it will not open automatically from the next time),Goto Eclipse Help-->DashBoard.